# Ember.js - Routing from a prefixed url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I need to create a resource starting from a pre-defined URL. For example, I have a mini blog component which I would like to create using Ember.js. This blog is on a url of 'http://example.com/user/:slug' which is from a Rails route. :slug is a friendly_id of the users name.

How would I configure this as a route in Ember so I can start developing the blog component? I would like the url to change to 'http://example.com/user/:slug/**blog**' where ember will add the 'blog' to end of the url. I would also like to nest the url so it will add the :slug of the blogs title when clicked on: 'http://example.com/user/:slug/**blog/ember-js-routing**' However, I am assuming this is done by nesting the routes as in below.

```
@resource 'blog', ->
    @route 'show',
        path: '/:slug'
```

I just can't work out how to start the resource

**Edit 1**

To get the 'blog' to add to the URL I did the below in my routes. This works great, hopefully this is the right of doing it? But if I refresh the page Rails will through an error as it doesn't recognise the URL. This is correct as I haven't created a route for it in my Rails application. If I create the route then rails expects to see a controller and views but I don't want this as I want Ember.js to take control from the `blog` part of the URL.

```
App.UserIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
    beforeModel: ->
      @replaceWith "blog.index"
      return
)
```

I'm starting to think Ember.js isn't what I want as I'm trying to building components and not single page applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Ember.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', {path: '/user'}, function() {
        this.resource('user', {path: '/:slug'}, function() {
            this.resource('blog', {path: '/blog'}, function() {
                this.route('post'), {path: '/:post_id'});
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Also, maybe this screencast that I gave earlier this year at Warm Croc Conf, might shed some more light into this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KH5RreHtaaQ

Edit1: 
To make Ember.js create an application that works "inside" an HTML element, you can use:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#app-container'
});
```

You might find that this is what you need :)

Comment: Thanks..I thought there might have been a better way of doing this. The problem I have now though is its not adding the `blog` to the end of the URL, any ideas why this might be happening? I will definitely be watching your video.

Comment: Ember.js is a framework to build Single Page Apps, so if you are after a widget or component libraries, there might be better alternatives out there... That being said, you can tell Ember to create an "SPA" inside of an HTML element, using:

    App = Ember.Application.create({
       rootElement: '#app-container'
    });

Comment: After many days trying I've decided to stick with rails and RJS. Its a shame these frameworks don't supply some kind of component integration instead of just a SPA. I'l accept your answer anyway as you answered my original question.